# Group similar items in array of objects

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello i have the following JSON:

```
        [
    {
      "name": "Donation",
      "collection": {
        "name": "Donation Company 1",
        "collection": {
          "id": 1,
          "category": "Donation",
          "name": "Some Donation",
          "price": 10,
          "description": "Hahahaha",
          "company": "Donation Company 1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Donation",
      "collection": {
        "name": "Donation Company 1",
        "collection": {
          "id": 2,
          "category": "Donation",
          "name": "Another Donation",
          "price": 50,
          "description": "LoL",
          "company": "Donation Company 1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Insurance Company 1",
      "collection": {
        "name": "Hehe",
        "collection": {
          "id": 3,
          "category": "Insurance",
          "name": "Lorem Ipsum Solor",
          "price": 25,
          "description": "Lmao",
          "company": "Insurance Company 1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Insurance Company 2",
      "collection": {
        "name": "Donation Company 1",
        "collection": {
          "id": 5,
          "category": "Insurance",
          "name": "Sample Extra",
          "price": 500,
          "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
          "company": "Insurance Company 2"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'm having trouble trying to group the similar items together, as in all items in the same category appear in the same category array.
And in each category all items that have the same company end up in the same company array.

This is an example what i am trying to accomplish, i used an online editor to construct the JSON:
[expected-json-output-when-saved](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=aad6ff58280f2bbdc3334dc42ae63507)

I used the laravel **collect()** helper function to construct my array of objects, i have tried several combinations in foreach loops and have been at it for hours but have still not been able to get the expected JSON returned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you `json_decode()` that JSON string and stored it in a `$json` variable, you can do the following:

```php
$collection = collect($json);

$collection = $collection->groupBy('collection.collection.category');
```

Dump the `$collection` variable to see the result.

Comment: Thank you for your input but i don't think you understood the question, the JSON object that is shown in my question is what is currently being returned to the client.  If you follow the link in my post you will see how i want the data to be returned instead.  I have already built the collection but am unable to get it to return in that way.

Comment: Hi. Perhaps you need to post the code that generated that JSON string as I don't think it came from a Laravel `Collection`. AFAIK, Laravel `Collection` should always appear as an array in JSON.

Comment: Oh sorry i think i was half asleep when i saw your post, i understand it now and yes it is indeed a collection.  With your help i was able to group by category to get this: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=aad6ff58280f2bbdc3334dc42ae63507

Comment: However there is the issue of the second grouping, i tried looping through the collection after the first grouping to further group the items by company as well but that didn't work out.